# how to redirect contact form

Tags: php, drupal, redirect, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How can I redirect the contact form in drupal 7 to a thank you page?  There are modules to do this ini drupal 6 but not for drupal 7 and I cant find how to do this with rules, there is no option for a rule when submitting the contact form.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Create your custom module with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) implementation. Then type something like

```
$form_state['#redirect'] = 'path/to/redirect';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this ,

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'user_register') {
    $form['#submit'] []= 'mymodule_node_form_submit_handler';
  }
}

function mymodule_node_form_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
unset($form['#redirect']);

    $form_state['redirect']  = 'http://google.com';

}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, because notice it's $form_state['redirect'] not $form_state['#redirect']